# What's wrong with my flash installation on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, browser, flash, plugins

I have installed Flash but it doesn't work and there's no note about it in the *about:plugins* page in Firefox. Here's my proof:

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: Could you add some info on how you installed Flash ?

Comment: I got a deb package from Adobe site and installed it. What else?

Comment: And I even did like this http://lazyubuntu.com/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-10-beta-2-on-ubuntu-804-hardy-heron.html but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Recommend going to Karmic anyway.

Help us a little here to help you...

Give us the results of these commands (the results shown are as on my Karmic system)

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
$ ls /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/
flashplugin-alternative.so  libjavaplugin.so
```

Run synaptic and select the flash plugin you installed to see what files it actually put where.

Ah! I see you got the .deb from Adobe. Hmm. No telling off hand what silly thing they may do... anyhoo, all the more important to find out where they put what, because unless that matches with where your firefox is Bad Things (like it not working) will happen.

Comment: one@one-desktop:/$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
one@one-desktop:/$ ls /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/
flashplugin-alternative.so
one@one-desktop:/$

Comment: installed files: 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/xulrunner
/usr/lib/xulrunner/plugins
/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons
/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins
/usr/lib/mozilla
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib/iceape
/usr/lib/iceape/plugins
/usr/lib/iceweasel
/usr/lib/iceweasel/plugins
/usr/lib/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/plugins
/usr/lib/midbrowser
/usr/lib/midbrowser/plugins
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/adobe-flashplugin

Comment: /usr/share/doc/adobe-flashplugin/copyright
/usr/share/doc/adobe-flashplugin/changelog.Debian.gz

Answer (score 0):

I found this little script from Internet which fix this problem always.

```
echo "Closing Firefox"
sudo killall -9 firefox     

echo "Downloading and instaling Getlibs for required libraries"
wget http://www.boundlesssupremacy.com/Cappy/getlibs/getlibs-all.deb
sudo dpkg -i getlibs-all.deb

echo "Removing previous installs of flash:"
sudo apt-get remove -y --purge flashplugin-nonfree gnash gnash-common mozilla-plugin-gnash swfdec-mozilla libflashsupport nspluginwrapper
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f ~/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -rfd /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper

echo "Installing ia32-libs and nspluginwrapper"
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs nspluginwrapper

echo "Getting libs"
sudo getlibs -p libcurl3
sudo getlibs -p libnss3-1d
sudo getlibs -p libnspr4-0d

echo "Installing Flash Player 10"
cd ~
wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz
tar zxvf install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz
sudo cp install_flash_player_10_linux/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
rm -rf ~/install_flash_player_10_linux/

echo "Linking the libraries so that firefox can see them."
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/plugins/npwrapper.libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/plugins/npwrapper.libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/

echo "Done :-)"
echo "You may re-start Firefox now"
```